# How to post multiple text files in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, post, http-post

I'm developing a node.js application. And I want to use HTTP POST for posting multiple local text files to target web server.

Now I use [request npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), so are there any ways to implement my goal with request npm? And of course, I will appreciate other solutions with different libraries.

I meant HTTP POST is executed by node.js itself, not client javascript. With node.js, I want to post multiple local text files to another server.

Comment: Check out multer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer and https://www.codementor.io/tips/9172397814/setup-file-uploading-in-an-express-js-application-using-multer-js

Comment: Sorry, I meant HTTP POST is executed by node.js itself, not client javascript. With node.js, I want to post multiple local text files to another server.

Comment: Examples of uploading using the `request()` library here right in the documentation: https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads

Comment: Thank you. I could do that with request() document.

Answer (score 0):

the most friendly method to send file is proposed by [needle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/needle)

```
var needle = require('needle');

var data = {
  file: '/home/johnlennon/walrus.png',
  content_type: 'image/png'
};

needle
  .post('https://my.server.com/foo', data, { multipart: true })
  .on('readable', function() { /* eat your chunks */ })
  .on('end', function() {
    console.log('Ready-o, friend-o.');
  })
```

or

```
needle.post('https://my.server.com/foo', data, {multipart: true},
function(err,result) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Also, i haven't tried, but documentation says that you can pass an array of objects

```
var data = [
    {
        file: '/home/johnlennon/walrus1.png',
        content_type: 'image/png'
    },
    {
        file: '/home/johnlennon/walrus2.png',
        content_type: 'image/png'
    }
]
```

Comment: Passing an array of objects does not work. I always ended up getting error: Unexpected Field in my server side.